# How to use Bootstrap tags input with Typeahead in MVC Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a problem using this script:
https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput

I have been trying to show a preload list of tags that filter the options when the user writes in the input field. I try with the example from the bootstrap-tagsinput documentation but it doesn't work :/.

My input is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tags, new { @class = "form-control", @data_role = "tagsinput", @id="tags" })
```

And the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var citynames = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            prefetch: {
                url: 'https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/assets/citynames.json',
                filter: function (list) {
                    return $.map(list, function (cityname) {
                        return { name: cityname };
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        citynames.initialize();

        $('#tags').tagsinput({
            typeaheadjs: {
                name: 'citynames',
                displayKey: 'name',
                valueKey: 'name',
                source: citynames.ttAdapter()
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:

In the bundle config I Added the reference of typeahead and bootstrap tags input, just like these:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                      "~/Scripts/global_script.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.js",
                      "~/Scripts/typeahead-0.11.1.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"));
```

Comment: Did you include typeahead.js (or the like)?